# How to dynamically add or remove columns / rows in a matrix?

Tags: java, matrix, ujmp

I'm using the Universal Java Matrix Package (UJMP) for handling matrices. My problem now is that the matrices are fixed in size but I would like to add or remove rows or columns.

Does somebody have an idea how this can be achieved efficiently without just creating a new matrix each time a row or columns gets added/removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that matrices in UJMP implement the `ObjectCalculations` interface, which has `deleteRows` and `deleteColumns` methods of various signatures that return either a new `Matrix` or a reference to a modified original matrix, depending on how they are called.

Comment: Thank you, I did not see it, I will check it out. But adding seems not to be natively supported.

Comment: @machinery - It's awkward, but I think you can insert rows or columns by first splitting the matrix in two (using `ObjectCalculations.submatrix()`) and then pasting the pieces back together with the additional rows or columns (using `MiscGeneralDoubleCalculations.appendHorizontally()` or `appendVertically()`). There may be a better way, but you can at least package up this way into a utility method or two.